# AbstractMethodError thrown at runtime with Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am absolutely new to Hibernate and JPA and I have the following problem trying to implement a tutorial that uses Hibernate following the JPA specification.

I have these classes:

1) A **`HelloWorldClient`** class, the entry point of my application, containing the `main` method:

```
package client;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import entity.Message;

public class HelloWorldClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("merging");

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction txn = em.getTransaction();
        txn.begin();

        Message message = new Message("Hello"); //transient state        
        em.persist(message); //persistent state        

        txn.commit();   
        em.close(); 

        message.setText("Hi"); //modifying the detached state of message

        EntityManager em2 = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction txn2 = em2.getTransaction();
        txn2.begin();

        //the returned mergedMessage is a persistent object
        //any changes to mergedMessage will be dirty checked when the txn2 will be committed and updated in the database
        Message mergedMessage = em2.merge(message);

        txn2.commit();
        em2.close();        


        //Detaching objects explicitly
        /*
        EntityManager em3 = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction txn3 = em.getTransaction();
        txn3.begin();

        Message msg = new Message("Howdy"); //transient state        
        em.persist(msg); //persistent state    

        em.detach(msg); //detaching the message object explicitly
        txn3.commit();
        em3.close();
        */  

    }
}
```

2) A **`Message`** entity class that is mapped on a database table:

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")  
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="TEXT")    
    private String text;

    public Message() {}
    public Message(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

3) And finally I have the **`persistence.xml`** configuration file in the **`META-INF`** folder of my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="merging" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>

            <!-- Database connection settings -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hello-world" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="myPassword" />

            <!-- SQL dialect -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />

            <!-- Create/update tables automatically using mapping metadata -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

            <!-- Pretty print the SQL in the log file and console -->
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I try to run my application, I obtain this error message in the stacktrace:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.getConfigurationValues()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at client.HelloWorldClient.main(HelloWorldClient.java:14)
```

Comment: Looks like some version issues. Check if Your hibernate libraries have the same version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had the same issue when trying to do hibernate tutorials. It usually means that there are compatibility issues between the jar files you added to your build path.

in your case, it would seem that 
          **org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.getConfigurationValues()**
appears in the latest version as an abstract method, hence the above error. Try changing the JPA jar to a previous version, that will probably solve the issue; that's what helped in my case.

Comment: Or try bumping the hibernate version. Guessing 4.3.8 to 4.3.10 on all hibernate dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and when I checked the Maven repository for hibernate-entity manager I found I wasn't specifying the latest version in my POM.xml.  Once I updated to the latest version it fixed the problem.