# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am facing with an error after I start spring boot application. In main code Read() function is working well but after executing it spring boot part does not start.

Main Application

```
package com.javainuse;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootHelloWorldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {         
                System.out.println("Debug Print");
                 Read();


        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.class, args);

    }

    private static void Read() throws IOException {
          System.out.println("Hacked by?");
        SessionFactory sf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/MONSTER/Desktop/Hello.xlsx")); 
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file); 
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
        Row row;
        for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){ 
            row = (Row) sheet.getRow(i);  //sheet number


                String id;
                if( row.getCell(0)==null) { id = "0"; }
                else id= row.getCell(0).toString();

                   String name;
                if( row.getCell(1)==null) { name = "null";}  
                   else name = row.getCell(1).toString();   //else copies cell data to name variable

                   String phone;
                if( row.getCell(2)==null) { phone = "null";   }
                   else  phone   = row.getCell(2).toString();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        Customer std = new Customer();
        std.setId((int) Double.parseDouble(id));
        std.setName(name);
        std.setPhone(phone);
        System.out.println(std.getId()+" "+std.getName()+" "+std.getPhone());
        session.saveOrUpdate(std);
        t.commit();     
        }

        file.close();
                System.out.println("Completed!");

    }



    }
```

Customer Class

```
package com.javainuse;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer", schema="excel")
public class Customer  {
    @Id
 //  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
        @Column
private String name;
        @Column
private String phone;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
public Customer(int id, String name, String phone) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
}
public Customer() {
    super();
}





}
```

Controller

```
package com.javainuse.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class helloController {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome.html")
    public ModelAndView firstPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("xd"); 
    }

}
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.javainuse</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootHelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringBootHelloWorld</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>3.14</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
     </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.1.Final</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin</artifactId>
      <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.4.RELEASE</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.getConfigurationValues()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.javainuse.SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.main(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.java:25) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.getConfigurationValues()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:404) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/excel</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.javainuse.Customer"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using different versions of hibernate-core and hibernate-entity-manager.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
     </dependency>

 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
```

Use the same versions of hibernate in pom.xml and make sure you have the same versions in classpath.

Similar problems:

[one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3219) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410111/abstractmethoderror-thrown-at-runtime-with-hibernate-jpa)